# couldn't load data from cursor to SimpleCursorAdapter, it consoles error that column _id does not exists.!

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, simplecursoradapter

Here is my Code

When I retrieved data from Cursor manually it was fine result, 
but when I create SimpleCursorAdapter and put a cursor into it, I gives me FATAL EXCEPTION

## MainActivity

```
package com.example.dummy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String T = "Main";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Student s = new Student(this);
        s.insert("Jeevan");
        s.insert("Wahab");
        s.insert("Majid");
        Cursor c = s.getAllStudents();
        ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] from = {DbTable.NAME};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, from, to, 0);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

## Student Class

```
package com.example.dummy;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class Student {

    private static final String T = "Student";
    private DbTable dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public Student(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DbTable(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public long insert(String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DbTable.NAME, name);
        long insert = 0;
        try {
            insert = db.insert(DbTable.TABLE, null, cv);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.d(T, "insert " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return insert;
    }

    public Cursor getAllStudents(){
        String[] columns = {DbTable.ID, DbTable.NAME};
        Cursor c = db.query(DbTable.TABLE,
                columns,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst() ) {
            return c;
        }
        return c;
    }

}
```

## DbTable Class

where table is created

```
package com.example.dummy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DbTable extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE = "STUDENT";
    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String NAME = "NAME";

    private static final String T = "DATABASE TABLE";

    private final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE
            + " ( '" + ID + "' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
            + "'"+NAME + "' VARCHAR NOT NULL );";

    public DbTable(Context context) {
        super(context, "MYDB", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try{
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Log.i(T, "database created");           
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.d(T, "error onCreate "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try{
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
            Log.i(T, "onUpgrade ");         
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.d(T, "onUpgrade "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: change `public static final String ID = "ID";` to `public static final String ID = "_id";`

Comment: The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) clearly states that you need a column named "_id".